# Not receiving transfer on different host

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to fetch html from a page with curl and php. I have the following code, which works perfectly on my host:

```
<?php

$curl   = curl_init();

$URLs[] = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

echo request( $curl, $URLs[0] );

function request($curl, $url, $post = null)
{
    echo (isset($post) ? 'POST ' . $url : 'GET ' . $url) . PHP_EOL;
    try 
    {
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array
        (
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION      => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER         => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER      => false,
            CURLOPT_URL                 => $url,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array
            (
                'Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
            )
            ));
            return  curl_exec($curl);
        }
    catch(Exception $exception)
    {
        echo $exception;
    }
}           
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

When I put it on my webhost, I get no response. I checked for curl error and it says 'No Url set!'. Any hints please? Thanks!

Comment: is your curl extension on webhost enabled ?

Comment: I believe so, it's listed in php_info and the curl would't give 'No Url Set' error I believe.

Answer (score 0):

try this other format of curl handling, initializing host in curl_init function:

```
    $url = ....
    $arrayConfig = ....

    $curl = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt_array($curl,$arrayConfig); 
    $content = curl_exec($curl); 
    $err     = curl_errno($curl); 
    $errmsg  = curl_error($curl) ; 
    $header  = curl_getinfo($curl); 
    curl_close($curl);
```